# Javascript Jquery, some alert won't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

alert("dfg"); fires several times, alert("asd") not once. Any idea why alert("asd") won't fire?

```
$(window).resize(function(){//shortens name if length would otherwise break line
    for(x in nameLabels){
            if($(nameLabels[x]).text()=="..."){
                $(nameLabels[x]).text(originalNameLabels[x]);
            }
            if($(nameLabels[x]).width()>$(window).width()*0.45 && !($(nameLabels[x]).width()==$(window).width())){
                $(nameLabels[x]).text("...");
            }
            alert("dfg");
    }
    alert("asd");
});
```

`alert("dfg")` fires several times, `alert("asd")` not once.
Any idea why `alert("asd")` won't fire?

Comment: copy paste code into questions, not images of code...,as for the asd not being alerted, have you check your console for errors, errors in code will stop the rest of the code from executing

Comment: I can't even read it... font is too small for my eyes

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: I bet green is your favorite color :)

Comment: Since you are using a for in loop you are probably looping over properties like functions etc which will cause errors.

Comment: even though the console reports nothing, i will try going over namelabels one by one, thanks, i will report if i find something

Comment: if `nameLabels` is a DOM collection, you can't reliably iterate over that using `for ... in`.  Host objects are their own beast to be treated with care.

Comment: Given that you're using jQuery anyway, why don't you use `$.each()` or instead of `for(in)`? Repeating `$(nameLabels[x])` four or five times in the same function is really inefficient.

Comment: i will also try that out, needless to say all this jQuery stuff is really new to me, thanks

Comment: Guys, I do not think this question deserves the number of down votes (5) or close votes (2) it has got at the moment. The only thing the OP has done wrong here is to use an image instead of text for his code. Apart from that, this is a legitimate question on SO.

Comment: @tgudelj If you would please edit your question to copy your code as text instead, some of the others might consider removing their negative votes.

Comment: Had i not also post the code in text format, along the picture aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no errors at all, there is no reason why that line should not get reached.

It is quite likely that for one of your `nameLabels`, one of the statement results in an error, aborting the execution within the loop, thus skipping the remainder of the function.

Check if this is the case by opening your console (`Ctrl+Shift+C` in both Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: i had already checked console and it reports nothing at all

Comment: Alright, indeed doing something with one particular member of nameLabels kept causing the problem and, Jeremy J Starcher was right, iterating over them using for...in was bad

Comment: Right, it is unusual that an error occurs, causing a function execution to exit prematurely, without leaving any trace on the console. Have you been able to isolate exactly what was wrong with it?

Comment: As an additional suggestion, try using a regular `for` loop, instead of a `for ... in` loop.

Comment: No, bguiz, i have not had any luck in finding out what exactly made it break, but i have had luck in finding another approach to what i was trying to do.